# Determining Data Type From Value in Row of CSV File

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, csv

I wrote a Python program that reads CSV files and spits them out as insert statements for MySQL. Now I want an additional program that is able to form the `CREATE` statements for each new table using the column headers. Due to MySQL formatting I need to be able to determine the type of each value in a column similar to the `type()` function in shell. My idea is to read the second row of a CSV file, after the column headers, and pull out values as separated by a `,` (i.e. one value from each column). Then take that value and run it through the `type()` function and return `int, str, float, etc.`. Later I will do some `if statements` with the value returned by `type()` to append the proper data type to the end of the column header for the `CREATE` statement.

So far I have managed to get as far as pulling each value out of a compiled list of the first row and printing the `type()` that it is. Only problem is that everything in a list is treated as a string so the only return is `<class 'str'>`. If I knew what type of value it was I would be able to convert from string to the correct type, but that defeats the whole purpose of the program. I am sure there is a better way to do it that doesn't spit the first row out as a list of strings, but I am not sure how to do that. Here is what I have so far as well as ideas with how to continue:

```
import csv, os

path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/file/test/'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(path +file) as inFile:
            with open(path + file[:-4] + ".txt", "w") as outFile:
                csvFile = csv.reader(inFile)
                columnHeader = next(csvFile)
                firstRow = next(csvFile)
                i = 0
                for value in firstRow:
                    valueType = (type(value))
                    for header in columnHeader:
                        if valueType = class 'str': # Don't think this formatting is correct
                            columnHeader.append(' varchar (255)')
                        if valueType = class 'int':
                            columnHeader.append(' int')
                        if valueType = class 'float':
                            columnHeader.append(' float')
```

I have also looked into using **[this](https://github.com/okfn/messytables)** library but would prefer to do it myself.

Are the methods I chose to do this plausible/possible? Are there any better ways you can think of to do it? If so, how?

Comment: it has been a while since i saw a good question. Thanks!! Two things come to mind: *a series of `try-except` blocks (`try: int(x), except: try: float(x), except str(x)`) or something using `eval` which would be very elegant.

Comment: @MarcB That is precisely what I said above. These CSV files have huge amounts of data in them so doing this manually isn't plausible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the *simple* way to do it:

```
def find_type(a):
    try:
        var_type = type(int(a))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            var_type = type(float(a))
        except ValueError:
            var_type = type(a)
    return var_type

a = ['123123', '11.21', 'Some Bank', '11/2/1995']

print([find_type(x) for x in a])
#[<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

I am pretty sure that there are more elegant ways though.

Comment: I was not even aware of the `try: except:` function but this is exactly what I was looking for. Now I still have to play around with it a bit to get it to work exactly how I wanted but this definitely gets me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility to distinguish between float and int and assume that everything else is a string.  If the value has a decimal point then it tries to convert it to a float and tries to convert it to an int if not.  If either conversion fails, the value is left as a string.

```
if '.' in val:
    try:
        val = float(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
else:
    try:
        val = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for as well, except I chose @Ev. Kounis' answer because it makes more sense to me to run multiple `try:` and `except:` statements with each other rather than putting them in another `if: else:` statement. However I am still thankful that you took the time to provide a quality answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ThoseKind Using the `if else` statement if faster by a factor of ~3 on my system.  Regardless of what solution you use, it is generally bad practice to except all errors in a `try except` statement; you should specify the `ValueError` which is what python raises if it can not do the type conversion.

Comment: I realized my comment came across differently than I intended it. I was referring to the fact that running the `try: except:` statements within your specified `if:` loop might result in an error for me because I am not sure which values contain `'.'`. I do agree that this would work and probably is better practice in general, but in my specific situation I'm not entirely sure that this would work for every value.